Averaging classification result vs direct infer
Suppose I have tensor X_test with this shape:
(10,2,512) Where:

10 is num of ID
2 is num of Channel of every ID, let's say channel A and B.
512 is model input and output size.

My model accept vector with shape 512 and returning vector with shape 512 too. Hence when predict, it accept (batch_size, 512).
The output returning one-hot encoded with 4 classes (batch_size, 512, 4) that will be converted to integer encoding (batch_size, 512).
Problem
How to report classification metrics Based on ID, let's say F1-Score of every ID regardless channels type being used. Therefore it will has ten F1-score.
There are two options:

Using Direct Infer
Averaging Metric Result

Direct Infer
Direct infer means, there is no average calculation of metrics result after infer. The result directly showed up after comparing ground truth and predicted.
Suppose I perform infer like this:
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_batched)

Where X_test_batched has shape (20, 512) where 20 is reduced dimension from ID dimension and channel dimension a.k.a 10 x 2.
Hence, y_pred has shape (20, 512) and can be converted back to (10, 2, 512) that lead us to convert tensor into (10, 1024).
Suppose, there is blackbox function to calculate F1-Score that accept two vectors of ground truth and predicted, get_f1().
With this, we can answer the question where we get the result based on ID.
get_f1(y_true[0,:], y_pred[0,:]) # f1 result of first ID
...
get_f1(y_true[9,:], y_pred[9,:]) # f1 result of last ID

Where y_true and y_pred have shape 10, 1024.
Averaging Metric Result
Same, there will be ten F1 score reports because it's based on every ID.
But it achieved by averaging result of channels for every ID, suppose the y_true and y_pred has shape (10,2,512).
get_average(get_f1(y_true[0,0,:], y_pred[0,0,:]), get_f1(y_true[0,1,:], y_pred[0,1,:])) # F1 score of first ID
...
get_average(get_f1(y_true[9,0,:], y_pred[9,0,:]), get_f1(y_true[9,1,:], y_pred[9,1,:])) # F1 score of last ID

Question
Will both methods returning same result?
